# Mongo Types NumberInt NumberLong

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java

Using the Mongo Java Driver if you insert the following document:

```
Document Monday = new Document()
.append("counter",1)
.append("model1", data1)
.append("model2", data1)
.append("model3", data1)
.append("model4", data1);
```

counter I would have hoped would have been of type NumberInt(). What I have found is that it seems to end up as NumberLong(). So I have rewritten the above to be:

```
 int counter = 1;
Document Monday = new Document()
.append("counter",counter)
.append("model1", data1)
.append("model2", data1)
.append("model3", data1)
.append("model4", data1);
```

This creates NumberInt() for sure. When I do some update as follws:

```
if (counter>=4){counter=1;}else{counter++;}
loc = DoW.concat(".").concat("counter");
                collection.updateOne(and(eq("topic",topic),eq("sp",settlement)), new Document("$set", new Document(loc,counter)));
```

Will the type stay as NumberInt() or will it get converted by Mongo majic to a NumberLong(). This issue is when:

```
int counter = docday.getInteger("counter");
```

Does the change from 1 to int counter = 1; make sure that Mongo will use NumberInt() rather than NumberLong().

What controls this decision and how do I force a NumberInt() within Java Driver.

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed your question...

Comment: Does the edit help ?